# Virtual Technology

Tags: desktop-computer

I want turn on my Virtual Technology because some apps are asking me to do. And when I search for "How to enable VT?", I can find various solutions. But when I do the same, my screen shows some other display. There I can find the option of BIOS SYSTEM, asking me to press F10. And when I do so, I can't find the option of turning on Virtual Technology. So, Please help me!

Comment: Not all CPUs support virtualization. Perhaps yours doesn't?

Comment: If your firmware does not provide an option to enable then it cannot be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU needs to have a feature called SLAT (2nd lvl translation) to be able to run virtualisation. You should be able to check that on manufacturer's website.

- For Intel processors EPT (Extended Page Tables)
- For AMD processors RVI (Rapid virtualisation Indexing)